# Is there any ReturnType functionality for the Editor control like the Entry control contains?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, editor

The last field in my form is an Editor and I would like the Done option to appear on the keyboard. I know this can interfere with the function of skipping to the next line.

Comment: I am not sure what does it means ** I would like the Done option to appear on the keyboard**, can you give more detailed info or some screenshot here?

Comment: I mean something like Entry control with ReturnType = Done ```<Entry Placeholder=" Email" ReturnType="Done" />```